# Convert to relevant type if the variable is not null

Tags: c#, nullable

I am having trouble in mapping the results of a CRM query to my custom model if the value is null I am attempting to use the following code:

```
foreach (account acc in accounts.BusinessEntities)
{
    if ((acc.accountid != null))
    {
        try
        {
            Account newAccount = new Account();
            newAccount.AccountID = acc.accountid.Value;
            newAccount.MPRN = Convert.ToInt64(acc.new_mprnnumber);
            newAccount.CustomerNumber = acc.new_customernumber;
            newAccount.CurrentLiftDate = acc.new_preferredliftday.Value.Equals(DBNull.Value) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(acc.new_preferredliftday.Value);
            newAccount.MonthlyAmount = acc.new_regularliftamount.Value.Equals(DBNull.Value) ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(acc.new_regularliftamount.Value);
            newAccount.DepositDate = acc.new_depositdate.Equals(DBNull.Value) ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(acc.new_depositdate.ToString());
            newAccount.DepositAmount = acc.new_depositamount.Value.Equals(DBNull.Value) ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(acc.new_depositamount.Value);
            db.Accounts.Add(newAccount);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "ERROR CREATING ACCOUNT IN BILLING ENGINE : " + ex.Message, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

When the acc.new_depositdate is null then it will not let me set the value of the date to nullable date and it seems to be continuing to try to convert the null value as I am getting an object reference error

Comment: Do you mean `null` or `DBNull`?  If it's really `null`, then obviously, the call to `.Equals` will throw a null reference exception.  Please post your exact error message + stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

You can change:

```
newAccount.DepositDate = acc.new_depositdate.Equals(DBNull.Value) ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(acc.new_depositdate.ToString());
```

To

```
newAccount.DepositDate = acc.new_depositdate == null ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(acc.new_depositdate.ToString());
```

This way you're not trying to call `.Equals()` against a null value (which is likely the cause of your `NullReferenceException`).

You may also have to apply the change to the other assignments to prevent further exceptions.